# Move text over image using CSS

Tags: css

I've been able to get my text over top of my image to the top left using.

```
.block1 img {position:relative:}
```

And then I use

```
.text a {position:aboslute; top:0;}
```

With good success. The only problem is that I have a sticky navigation bar that has position:fixed applied to it. So the images go overtop of the sticky navigation bar.

Is there any way around this?

EDIT: Fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/WCwBv/4/

This should replicate the problem fairly closely.

Comment: Have you looked at `z-index`?

Comment: a lot of times, things like this can be fixed by adding a container for positioning only, separate from the elements themselves.

Comment: Have you tried to use `padding-top: height of your sticky bar` on your `body`?

Comment: Note that there is a typo: `aboslute` should be `absolute`. Can you demonstrate your problem? It's a little difficult to understand what exactly is wrong. Can you post the HTML, and enough CSS to reproduce the problem?

Comment: could you provide a fiddle please?

Comment: Will, my knowledge with z-index is very limited.

Comment: mcrtr, if I did that wouldn't I still have to use position relative? Dark, I'm not sure how to get that code working. Also fiddle is now provided.

Comment: Could you remove all unnecessary code from your fiddle? :)

Comment: Yeah, not sure why I added bootstrap! Hows this? http://jsfiddle.net/WCwBv/4/

Comment: Does this solve your problem? http://jsfiddle.net/WCwBv/5/

Comment: Hey Dark Ashelin; that was perfect! Thanks man! Appreciate it. :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone! z-index:1; on the stick navigation bar works perfectly. :)